# Why is Haskell so large?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm new to Haskell and so far quite enjoying it. One thing that strikes me is that it seems quite large, with many syntactical constructs and libraries that define functions for just about everything. For example, Data.Map defines almost 100 functions. Data.Set also defines many functions, as does Data.List, which also provides alot of the same functionality as Data.Set.

I have my beginner's opinion on why this might be (provide functions for all common patterns, reduce noise), but I'm interested to hear some veteran opinions on the topic.

Comment: Voted to close: this is a great question, but is very opinion-centric and not a good fit for SO. I recommend a self-post on [/r/haskell](http://reddit.com/r/haskell)

Comment: Fair enough, [here it be](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/sb80y/why_is_haskell_so_large/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the size of the Haskell language is somewhere in the middle (larger than Lisp, smaller than C++). Although since all the syntactic sugar has well defined translations down to Haskell Core (which has about 7 elements), its a bit hard to distinguish between library and language.

Its true that the libraries do contain a lot of small functions, basically because Haskell programmers have found patterns that kept turning up and then put them into code. As a learner I often had the feeling "there ought to be a function to do that" and then discovering that there was. You learn them in the same way as they were written: write the function yourself, and then find it in the documentation for some library a few days later.

Comment: “larger than Lisp” Do you mean Scheme? Common Lisp is notorious for being huge, and Scheme was actually created in reaction to it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: even Common Lisp is rather tiny compared to many modern languages. — C++ isn't actually _that_ huge. It just has a lot of different ways to do things.

Comment: @PascalCuoq are you saying that Scheme was created in anticipation of an upcoming huge Common Lisp :)?

Comment: @Peteris Oh, right, I mixed things up. From the Wikipedia page in my language, “in the seventies [...] the goal of [Scheme]'s creators was to purify Lisp while maintaining essential aspects” (this sentence is not on the English version of the page), and the first book on Common Lisp was in 1984 (although Common Lisp was standardized only in 1994).

Comment: Oh dear, I fear I've started something I won't be able to stop.  When I talked about the size I was actually thinking of the syntax (i.e. S-exprs) rather than the huge list of built-in functions.